# Может ли Hibernate мапить не на все поля класса?

Tags: hibernate

Возможно ли такое, в принципе? Допустим, у нас есть таблица, содержащая четыре поля id, name, birthday, age. Класс Entity Integer id, String name, Date birthday, Integer age, поля которого помечены соответствующими аннотациями. Но если мы в запросе делаем SELECT, только по name, возможно ли отобразить его на класс Entity и как это сделать?

Comment: Есть способы. Вам зачем?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev чтобы не менять архитектуру приложения, не писать новые классы-сущности.

Comment: Оригинально! А вам ORM точно нужен?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Ага, то есть есть уже готовое приложение, оно очень большое. У него есть уже свои классы и интерфейсы, ссылки типа которых можно передать в качестве параметров в различные методы (то есть свой api). И данные из таблиц (но не все), соответственно, нужно отобразить на эти классы, чтобы не вносить серьёзные изменения в код. Не могли бы вы привести ссылки, примеры, где можно почить как это можно сделать или ответить здесь?

Comment: В этой ситуации не вижу способа более простого, чем исправление сущностей.

Comment: Похоже на преждевременную оптимизацию. Если в результате выборки возвращается менее сотни записей, то большого значения не имеет 4 поля будут считаны или одно, по крайней мере если такие запросы выполняются реже 10 раз в секунду: просто берите самую легкую сущность и всё. К тому же, похоже на попытку получить ответ на изначально неправильно поставленный вопрос: вы уже приняли решение и спрашиваете как его реализовать, но далеко не факт что это решение верное - опишите решаемую задачу

Comment: @bobzer , да, верно, решение уже принято и возможно вопрос неправильно поставлен. Правильная постановка: как реализовать?). Решаемая задача - есть бд, нужно сделать "снимок" некоторых её таблиц и передать на другое устройство в формате json. Для этого нужно использовать hibernate и готовые сущности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*нужно использовать hibernate и готовые сущности*" - hibernate можно использовать и без сущностей: запрос `select name from User` вернёт список Object-ов (`List<Object>` - при выборке одного поля, `List<Object[]>` - при выборке нескольких полей), содержащих значение поля `name`. Можно использовать `HQL` указав имя класса сущности и вызвав метод `createQuery`: `SELECT name FROM User`. Можно использовать `SQL` указав имя таблицы и вызвав метод `createNativeQuery`: `SELECT name_field FROM users_table`.

Если без сущностей никак не обойтись, то добавьте в сущность конструктор без параметров и конструктор с параметром `String name`, и выполните запрос `select new User(name) from User`. В результате получите список экземпляров сущности, у которой объявлено несколько полей, но непустое поле только одно - `name`.

```
//конструктор без параметров нужен для соответствия спецификациям
public User() {
}

//конструктор для вашего HQL-запроса
public User(String name) {
  this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я бы проголосовал за Ваш ответ, если бы мог) Он, действительно полезен, в части того, что hibernate можно использовать без сущностей. Но в таком случае, нужно использовать createNativeQuery?

Comment: @VasiliyPumpkin нет, в ответе используется HQL.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev , в первой части ответа, думаю,  это возможно. Во второй, есть уже сущность User.

Comment: я дополнил ответ: в первом варианте можно использовать и HQL и SQL, во втором - только HQL